# element decelerateinterpolator must be declared error

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, visual-effects

I tried to create a `decelerateInterpolator` as in the example from [Android Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html) to declare a `decelerateInterpolator`:

> EXAMPLE: XML file saved at res/anim/my_overshoot_interpolator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <overshootInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:tension="7.0"
    /> This animation XML will apply the interpolator:
```

> This animation XML will apply the interpolator:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/my_overshoot_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="3.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="700" />
```

Mine was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<decelerateInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:factor="1"
/>
```

But I got the following error: `element decelerateinterpolator must be declared error`.
The code compiles but I got no effect in the Activity transition below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:interpolator="@animator/my_interpolator"
        android:fromYDelta="8%"
        android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
</set>
```

What is causing this error?

P.S.: And yes, I did call `overridePendingTransition` with the transition above

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not. If I ever do I'll post it here.

Comment: I have one question for you. Are you sure you are adding this to your "anim" folder, and not your drawable folder? For animations, you should create a folder called "anim" and then reference that. Set does not exist in drawable.

Comment: Yes, I used "anim" folder